# Simple ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose i have an ODE $$f(y'',y',y,x) = 0.$$

Does the domain of $x$ where $f$ is defined have anything to do with the domain in which a solution $y = g(x)$ satisfies the equation ?

Knowing , a priori , the domain of $x$ where $f(y'',y',y,x)$ is defined, do I know in advance something about the domain of the solution $y = g(x)$ that satisfies it ? Is there any relation between those domains ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you are talking about. Take $$ y' = 1 + y^2, \; \; y(0) = 0.  $$ You get $$  y = \tan x, \; \; - \pi / 2 < x < \pi / 2. $$

Comment: Nice to see you here +1